# How would you do this without a bunch of if/else statements?

Tags: c++, if-statement

I was playing GTA IV recently and I noticed an interesting feature. I was in a cab and switched to a specific station. Niko then said something about that station.

I was wondering how they might have done this. The only way I can think of is to have an if/else statement that goes through each station and sees if that's the one he is currently listening to.

Is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: the most common ways to 'clean-up' if/else or switch logic include creating a dictionary or using dynamic polymorphism. I think this case is more likely to have been done with a dictionary.

Comment: The term you are looking for is "data-driven design" or something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an enum, array of places, then you can have a piece of code like:

```
    currentStation = .. get the current station
playSound(stations[currentStation]);
```

Comment: this can also be done with a `string` and a `map` or hash table or database or some similar setup. It is sometimes referred to as creating a dictionary.

Comment: Another option would be to use pointers to function for feedback operations like sounds based on the current location. The set of pointer to functions would be updated as the location changed, though if the functions are not called fairly often, it's adding overhead to the code, in which case the suggested get current location to use as a current state and calling common functions based on the current state would work. The state could be used to index an array of pointers to sound types or more generally an array of pointers to functions for feedback.

Answer (score 1):

They likely do this by having a station change trigger an event.  Niko is set to as a listener for this type of event.  His characters programmed response to this event is to playback a certain sound.